# Hyperlinks getting rewritten in html email template

Tags: html, html-email, email-templates

I have a link (link to my website) inside the template like this:

```
<td width="144">
    <a href= "www.bgrnature.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="" width="76" height="58" border="0" alt=""/>
    </a>
</td>
```

But after sending the html email template to recipient, the hyperlink gets rewritten. Why does this happen?

[Check my link here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/premailer/1b25bce2a22f5c2eb5098eda792e82aa.html?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJGV6CM4KYKPTRSHA&Expires=1467322782&Signature=1h80oXa%2Bp%2BrS8Tnyenu%2BP2NGC6A%3D)

Comment: Add `http://` -  `<a href= "http://www.bgrnature.com/" target="_blank">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are missing `http://` thats why URL gets appended on current url as a sub-directory
 Try to add `http://`

`<a href= "http://www.bgrnature.com/" target="_blank">`

Comment: Thank you. Silly one, but didn't realize it could cause issue